# Show items not in array after form submit

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a dropdown menu which I am generating from an array like this(using fake data in this example for brevity)

```
    var city = document.getElementById("city");
    locarr = ["1", "2", "3", "4"];
    for(var i=0; i < locarr.length; i++) {
        var opt = locarr[i];
        var el = document.createElement("option");
        el.text = opt;
        el.value = opt;
        city.add(el);
    }
```

And that works fine, it populates the menu. However, when I submit the form and page reloads, I want to show the initial selected item and then all other items in the array excluding that one so I don't have a duplicate entry.

My `oldInput.city` value is coming from the controller which is the value that was posted upon form submission.

In its current state I have duplicate values once the form has been submitted.

```
<select class="chosen-select-no-single" name="city" id="city">
    <% if (!oldInput.city) { %>
    <option value="">Select City</option>
    <% } else { %>
    <option value="">Select City</option>
    <option value="<%= oldInput.city %>" selected>
        <%= oldInput.city %>
    </option>
    <% } %>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just delete oldInput from the HTML. In the for clause you can do this :

```
for(var i=0; i < locarr.length; i++) {
    var opt = locarr[i];
    var el = document.createElement("option");
    el.text = opt;
    el.value = opt;
    var oldInpt="<%=oldInput%>";
    if (oldInpt!=null && opt ==oldInpt.city){
       el.selected = true;
    }
    city.add(el);
}
```

Comment: thanks for that. But if I use your code then when I load the page for the first time the drop down menu is completely empty.

Comment: @user8463989 maybe the console is throwing an error? The dropdown should be loading the same way as before, the only thing that can change is the selected attribute for the option you wanted.

Comment: i think it has something to do with this as `oldInput.city` is declared with Node.js EJS, ie: `<%= oldInput.city %>` in my code but in your code oldInput isn't defined as it is a javascript variable there, not node.js

Comment: Sorry oldInput has to go between <% %>. I edited the answer. You should also check that oldInput is not null.

Comment: I am putting this code in <script> tags in my footer area. Is that where you suggest it goes because I can't use EJS syntax there?

Comment: Yes you can do it there, it is just a matter of format, <%=oldInput%> should print the variable, I edited the code again, but something around those lines should work.

Comment: If that does not work you can try again with   `if ( opt == <%=oldInput.city%>){` I was missing the = sign

Comment: Did you change the HTML to: `<select class="chosen-select-no-single" name="city" id="city">
    <option value="">Select City</option>
</select>`

Comment: Aha, that was it! Thanks!